# How to avoid sending Community Welcome Email from Apex when "Send welcome email" in the community email setup is true

Tags: apex, community

I have a piece of code in the API that goes like this:

```
if(something){
   //Must not send email
   Site.createExternalUser(user, AccountId, password, false);
}
else{
   //Need to send email
   Site.createExternalUser(user, AccountId, null, true);
}
```

If I turn off "Send welcome email", email is not being sent in both the cases.
If I keep it true, email is being sent in both the cases even if the 4th parameter is false in createExternalUser()

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off "Send welcome email", and in second case just send email with `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.

For example, if forth parameter in `createExternalUser(...)` is true, then add some code like:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
// add anything necessary to email here
Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{email});
```

UPDATE:

You can set merge fields with EmailTemplate (where templateData is Map of your fields names to fields values):

```
EmailTemplate template = [
    SELECT Id, Name, Subject, HtmlValue
    FROM EmailTemplate
    WHERE DeveloperName = :YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME
];

//...

String body = template.HtmlValue;
for (String key : templateData.keySet()) {
    if (templateData.get(key) == null) {
        templateData.put(key, '');
    }

    body = body.replace('{{' + key + '}}', templateData.get(key));
}
email.setHtmlBody(body);
```

Comment: @marria thanks for the reply. I tried to send using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage but the merge fields are not working.

Comment: @Divya I have updated the answer, you can use your EmailTemplate.